# Regarding ECMP hashing

Tags: bgp, ecmp

Assume we have a following topology.
`R1` represents Router1, `R2` represents Router2, `R3` represents Router3 and `R4` represents Router4.

`Src` represents the source Server.

`Dest` represents the destination.

There are 3 distinct paths to reach from Source server to the destnation.

`R1--R2--R4` is path1,
`R1--R4` is path2,
`R1--R3--R4` is path3.

**Assume, all of these are equal cost paths**.
BGP is running as the routing protocol and maximum paths is enabled for BGP.

Hence, we will have all the 3 paths to reach from R1 to R4.To be more precise, R1 will have all the 3 paths installed in the routing table, to reach R4.

**Question1:**

Let's say there is an application (which uses TCP) running on `Src` on port number 6811 and performing a transaction to destination on port number 53 for a period of 30 minutes.

So calculating the hash based on
Source IP, Destination IP, Source Port, Destination Port and Protocol,we would get a unique hash value and this would be a TCP flow.

I believe that out of the 3 distinct paths mentioned above, only 1 of the paths will be used (even though we have BGP ECMP enabled). The remaining 2 paths will be unused since the hash value remains unchanged for those 30 minutes.

Is the above understanding correct ?

**Question 2:**
Let's say there is another application (which uses TCP) running on `Src` on port number
6812 and performing a transaction to destination on port number 64 for a period of 10 minutes.
(Note: source port and destination port have changed as compared to Question 1 scenario).
So calculating the hash based on
Source IP, Destination IP, Source Port, Destination Port and Protocol.
We would get a unique hash value and this would be a different TCP flow. This hash value will definitely be different from the one calculated in Question1.

I believe that out of the 3 distinct paths mentioned above, only 1 of the paths will be used (even though we have BGP ECMP enabled). 
The remaining 2 paths will be unused since the hash value remains unchanged for those 10 minutes.

Is the above understanding correct ?

[image]

Comment: Looks like homework...

Comment: :) not, homework, i created the scenario on my own and trying to get clarity.

Comment: ECMP stands for "*equal-cost* multipath routing" - you've not mentioned the route costs at all...

Comment: already mentioned, all the paths are equal costs.

Comment: Paths or links of equal cost? *Paths* is highly unlikely, being of unequal lengths.

Comment: @Zac67 i meant to say that R1 has three equal cost paths in its routing table to reach R4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on both questions.  To make it simpler: ECMP and its hashing algorithm selects a path **per flow**.  So, a single flow will always use the same path *.

While the aggregate bandwidth of ECMP is the sum of all the links, a single flow cannot exceed the bandwidth of a single link.

* Per-packet ECMP is available in some scenarios, but is almost never used in actual networks.

Comment: One question here. In an ECMP path(consider 2 path ECMP), if one of the path(say path-1) goes down, all the flows will be mapped the remaining one path(say path2). Now, after a while, if the path1 comes back up, how will the load balancing happen ? Will some the flows will be forcefully re-mapped to the recovered path ?